# How can I use the word "both" correctly?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to use `both` in my sentence. However, I do not know whether I used it correctly or not.

Here is my sentence:

`For both the bivariate and multivariate model, the new model shows a significant performance.`

Is this correct? I think I cannot use `the` after `both`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `the` after `both`. However, using `both` makes the first clause plural.  The clause would need to end with `multivariate models,`. If you wanted it to remain singular, choosing either but not both, then you would use `either` instead of `both`. Since the second clause is definitely singular, `either` would be a better choice.

I hope you don't mind me going beyond your question. The sentence is a little awkward, repeating the noun 'model' in close proximity. It might sound slightly better as:

`For either bivariate or multivarite, the new model ...`, or even
`Whether bivariate or multivarite, the new model ...`